# How do I disable forwarding reference behavior without disabling template argument deduction?

Tags: c++, templates, rvalue-reference, template-argument-deduction

Consider the following:

```
template<class T>
void Destroy(T&& t) {
    // Do something dangerous to `t`
}
```

The author intends write a function that accepts any rvalue and does something that destroys it. However, that's not what happens here -- if `Destroy` is called with a lvalue `U`, `T` is deduced as `U&`, and `t` has type `U&` after reference collapsing. That means it compiles for lvalues, when the author wanted such calls to fail to compile.

One can't disable the reference collapsing (e.g.

```
template<class T>
void Destroy(typename remove_reference<T>::type&& t) {
    // Do something dangerous to `t`
}
```

) because the `::` disables template argument deduction completely.

Is the only way out here to `static_assert`?

```
template<class T>
void Destroy(T&& t) {
    static_assert(!is_lvalue_reference_v<T>, "Don't call with lvalues!");
    // Do something dangerous to `t`
}
```

Comment: `template<class T> void Destroy(T& t) = delete;`? Also, I think you mean lvalues, not glvalues.

Comment: @T.C.: That may work :) And you're right on lvalues.

Comment: what's wrong with `static_assert`?

Comment: @Bryan: Maybe nothing. But was curious anyway.